# Flutter Android freeze in between views

Tags: flutter

[Flutter freeze in between views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQL4H.png)

My flutter app appears to stuck in between two views, login_view and home_view. This issue is occurring in Android only. Any idea why this is happening? Does it have to do with my Android emulator? Thank you in advance!

login_view_model.dart

```
class LoginViewModel extends BaseModel {

  final AuthenticationService _authenticationService = locator<AuthenticationService>();
  final DialogService _dialogService= locator<DialogService>();
  final NavigationService _navigationService = locator<NavigationService>();

  Future login ({@required String email, @required String password}) async {
    setBusy(true);
    var result = await _authenticationService.loginWithEmail(email: email, password: password);
    setBusy(false);

    if (result is bool) {
      if (result) {
        _navigationService.navigateTo(HomeViewRoute);
      } else {
        await _dialogService.showDialog(title: 'Login Failure', description: 'General login failure. Please try again later');
      }
    } else {
      await _dialogService.showDialog(title: 'Login Failure', description: result);
    }
  }

  void navigateToSignUp() {
    _navigationService.navigateTo(SignUpViewRoute);
  }
}
```

home_view.dart

```
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeView({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('Home'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you just need to wrap your home_view with Scaffold?

Comment: Yup, that solves it

Comment: Added answer for others, it could be any widget which already consists of Material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally for every navigation, your page should be wrapped with Material(it also could be Material/Scaffold/SafeArea)